# UTF8 component in URL, should it be case sensitive?

Tags: http, url, url-rewriting, googlebot

I understand URL should be case-sensitive, e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/test.php


http://www.example.com/TEST.php
```

Should be two things.

But should the UTF-8 also be case sensitive, e.g. ?

```
http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A7%82%E6%B5%8B%E5%A4%A9%E6%96%87%E5%AD%A6
```

vs

```
http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%e8%a7%82%e6%b5%8b%e5%a4%a9%e6%96%87%e5%ad%a6
```

Should they be equal?

The reason I ask is: Googlebot keep using the upper case viarant of the URL, although my site is all using lower case url.

Comment: FWIW, bit.ly shortens them to the same URL http://bit.ly/QeUCWg, so they apparently decode it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak with 100% authority on this question, but if you stop to think about how the URL would be stored in a search index, or table of urls, or any of the myriad data stores Google uses, I can't imagine that the URLs would not be normalized in some fashion.

Any kind of normalization should decode the URL into a string, so there should be no difference.  I would be surprised if Google stored URLs with the % encodings.  They can store text in UTF-8; the percent signs are there to make things visible to humans.

Google "use" of the uppercase variant is simply for display and reporting purposes, I would guess.  I do not think the URL encodings are stored at all.

Comment: I disagree. Urls are not encoded in any specific way, so they can be either UTF-8, latin-1, or anything else. Decoding these may all result in the same 'string', but they are not the same url. Because urls don't give a specific definition the bytes, they are in fact different. However, the example given by OP are identical :)

Answer (score 0):

Since they are supposed to be pairs of hexadecimal characters, the lowercase and uppercase variants of encoded characters should be considered equivalent (e.g. 0xab and 0xAB are the same value).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Googlebot it's hard to predict where it's getting it's information from. Even if you only link to it with the lowercase and it's in your XML sitemaps in lowercase, there could be someone out there linking to your site with them in uppercase.

You are correct that Google treats URLs as case sensitive. Which is why they support the [rel=canonical specification](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394). If you're using the rel=canonical spec correctly, I wouldn't worry that Googlebot is accessing the URLs with all caps. When they process the page for indexing, it will consolidate all the page "value" to the canonical URL.

If you want to be even more explicit about it, you can 301 redirect all cap case requests to the lower case version. So Googlebot will follow the 301s to the lowercase version.

Also note, even if you have a 301 and rel=canonical ... you'll see that Googlebot will continue to crawl URLs with all caps. This will happen even if these URLs 404 or 410. Basically Googlebot never forgets a URL, and from time to time it'll try old URLs it knows existed at one point, or have links still pointing to it ... even if they're years old and long gone.

Answer (score 0):

Percent-encoded parts of the url should be normalized into the same url. This wikipedia page should give you all the answers ;)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization